# Node.js/Express - Ajax calls from local/external- network

Tags: ajax, node.js, express

I have a express instance listening on 3000.
A Http-server listening on 8080 and cors-proxy running on 1337 relaying info between them.
(npm http-server and npm cors-proxy, both installed globaly)

I can access the website from both local- and external-networks, but none of the ajax calls goes through. There are no POST/GET requests on the http-server when I launch the AJAX calls either.

Error from local network:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Error from external network:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header ....
```

My AJAX post request:

```
$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            //url: "http://localhost:1337/localhost:3000/name/"+inputText,
            url: "http://192.168.10.50:1337/192.168.10.50:3000/name/"+inputText,
            data: {"data": "Hello world"},
            success: (data) => {
                console.log("Success" + data);
            };
});
```

I've tried to add code in my node file to allow this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    red.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
})
```

But nothing changes.

How can I tell the http-server to let requests pass though from local and external networks?

Comment: What is this: `url: "http://192.168.10.50:1337/192.168.10.50:3000/name/"`?

Comment: Thats for the routing through corrs-proxy, it's running on :1337